# Predicting in Cox’s time varying proportional hazard model (theoretically as well as using Python)

Tags: python, survival, prediction, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

Are there any ideas on predicting the remaining lifetime (say at time $t_0$) in Cox’s time varying proportional hazard model? Im interested in theoretical ideas as well as practical ones for the following use case.

**My use case:** My training data consists of 100 samples of an engine running until failure (time is discrete) and sensor values for every cycle. For instance, the first sample looks like this:

`cycle      s1      s2      s3      s4      s5
   1       5.5     1.5     1.2     2.7     9.1
   2       5.6     1.5     1.1     2.9     8.3
  ...      ...     ...     ...     ...     ...
  137      0.5     9.9     7.8     9.3     1.1`

Cycles are different for each sample. The engine breaks in the last cycle.

Furthermore, I have test data (identical format), where I don't know the time until failure, i.e. I want to predict it. Thus my idea was to fit a Cox’s time varying proportional hazard model.

**The model:** is given by the hazard function 
$$ \lambda(t, \{Z(u)\}_{u \leq t}) = \lambda(t, Z(t)) = \lambda_0(t)\exp(Z(t) \cdot \beta)$$
where $Z$ denotes the time-varying covariates, i.e. (s1, ..., s5).
I know that $\beta$ and $\lambda_0$ can be estimated (in Python, the lifeline package can be used), but **how to proceed from here?**

I know that in the time-independent case, this prediction task boils down to calculating $$\mathbb{E}(T-t_0 \mid T \geq t_0) = \frac{1}{S(t_0)} \int_{t_0}^\infty S(t) \, dt,$$
where $S$ denotes the survival function, but I can't even see how to model this task purely theoretically.